# How to Not Force Login After Users Close Their Browser on gae

Tags: python, google-app-engine, session, authentication

...Like Django's session or cookies

Does anyone have a simple way of allowing this?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't seem to make sense of this.

Comment: I think he is asking about persistant sessions, i.e., if a user closes a window with his site open, then goes back to it later, how do you remember that they were already logged in, like Gmail.  I only have to log in once a day or so to that even if I close out my browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Application Settings in the App Engine dashboard, you can choose either 1 day, 1 week, or 2 week cookie expiration, assuming you're using the Users API.

I don't believe the cookie should ever be set to expire when the browser is closed, unless the user's browser setting is causing this behavior.  I can certainly stay logged in to my applications when restarting my browser.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of session libraries that let you do persistent sessions on App Engine; Nick's Blog has a good article [here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/02/Webapps-on-App-Engine-Part-5-Sessions) showing off both `Beaker` and `gaeutilities` session facilities in a concise manner.